# How to split react children to render in 2 different container components when the window resizes?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have 10 children that I pass to a component. If the component resizes some children don't fit into the component then I want to put them into a "..." menu, so the user can expand this button and a menu-like ux  will appear to show them.

This is the clear case:
component A with children [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
The window resizes it will be:
component A with children [1,2,3,4,5] and component B with children [5,6,7,8,9,10]

Comment: could you provide your code on sandbox with your css